# Disable scripting for a particular vhost

Tags: apache-2.2, php, opensuse, mono

I want to disable every form of scripting (PHP, ASP.NET, CGI) for a specific vhost in my Apache2 setup. Only plain old HTML pages.

Scripting must remain enabled for all other vhosts in the server.

It's not a security concern, it's a commercial concern (customer pays less for hosting)

Is it possible and how can I do that?

[Edit] From what I've found around the web, I'm going to try the following

```
RemoveHandler .php .phtml .php3
RemoveType .php .phtml .php3
RemoveHandler .aspx .ascx .ashx .asmx .asax .soap .rem axd .cs .vb .master .sitemap .resources. skin .browser .webinfo $
RemoveType .aspx .ascx .ashx .asmx .asax .soap .rem axd .cs .vb .master .sitemap .resources. skin .browser .webinfo .re$
php_flag engine off
```

This selectively disables PHP and .NET which are the only scripting runtimes installed

Comment: @Fuzzyfelt I haven't tried anything yet because I was very confused about **how** to do it before reading answer and a few articles about PHP

Answer (score 0):

Try `SetHandler default-handler` in the vhosts in question.

Compare: [Apache Handler documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/handler.html).